# Android Studio - create database with multiple columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I want to create a database with 3 columns (name of point of interest, longitude and latitude). Since I am completely new to databases I am using an example I found online and try to change it to my case. The problem is it works for 1 column but if I add the other 2 it breaks. This is my code:

> TaskContract

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class TaskContract {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "com.example.TodoList.db.tasks";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String POI_NAMES = "tasks";
    public static final String LONGITUDES = "longs";
    public static final String LATITUDES = "lats";


    public class Columns {
        public static final String POI = "task";
        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String LONGITUDE = "long";
        public static final String LATITUDE = "lat";
    }
}
```

> TaskDBHelper

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class TaskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TaskDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
        String sqlQuery =
                String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "%s TEXT" + " %s LONGITUDE" + "%s LATITUDE)",
                        TaskContract.POI_NAMES, TaskContract.Columns.POI,
                        TaskContract.LONGITUDES, TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE,
                        TaskContract.LATITUDES, TaskContract.Columns.LATITUDE);

        Log.d("TaskDBHelper","Query to form table: "+sqlQuery);
        sqlDB.execSQL(sqlQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB, int i, int i2) {
        sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TaskContract.POI_NAMES+TaskContract.LONGITUDES+TaskContract.LATITUDES);
        onCreate(sqlDB);
    }
}
```

and here's my main activity where I add the new values to the columns:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    private TaskDBHelper helper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Add a new point of interest");

                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                final TextView inputString1 = new TextView(this); inputString1.setText("Enter name:");
                final TextView inputString2 = new TextView(this); inputString2.setText("Enter longitude:");
                final TextView inputString3 = new TextView(this); inputString3.setText("Enter latitude:");
                final TextView inputString4 = new TextView(this); inputString4.setText("Enter a new point of interest:");

                final EditText inputField1 = new EditText(this);
                final EditText inputField2 = new EditText(this);
                final EditText inputField3 = new EditText(this);
                layout.addView(inputString4);
                layout.addView(inputString1);
                layout.addView(inputField1);
                layout.addView(inputString2);
                layout.addView(inputField2);
                layout.addView(inputString3);
                layout.addView(inputField3);
                builder.setView(layout);


                builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String poi = inputField1.getText().toString();
                        String longit = inputField2.getText().toString();
                        String lat = inputField3.getText().toString();

                        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();


                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.clear();
                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.POI,poi);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.POI_NAMES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);


                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE,longit);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.LONGITUDES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.LATITUDE,lat);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.LATITUDES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);


                        updateUI();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",null);

                builder.create().show();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.POI_NAMES,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.POI},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.task_view,
                cursor,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.POI},
                new int[]{R.id.taskTextView},
                0
        );

        this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    public void onDoneButtonClick(View view) {
        View v = (View) view.getParent();
        TextView taskTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskTextView);
        String poi = taskTextView.getText().toString();

        String sql = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s'",
                        TaskContract.POI_NAMES,
                        TaskContract.Columns.POI,
                        poi);


        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

I think the problem is when I declare *LONGITUDES* and *LATITUDES* in the TaskContract as if I change them like this:

> public static final String POI_NAMES = "tasks";
>
> public static final String LONGITUDES = "tasks";
>
> public static final String LATITUDES = "tasks";

it works but it puts everything in the same column.

Can someone explain what exactly means to assign the values "tasks" to my string?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code - for future reference you could check the what each method does [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)).

```
String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        "%s TEXT" + " %s LONGITUDE" + "%s LATITUDE)",
                        TaskContract.POI_NAMES, TaskContract.Columns.POI,
                        TaskContract.LONGITUDES, TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE,
                        TaskContract.LATITUDES, TaskContract.Columns.LATITUDE);
```

Here "TEXT" refers to the SQLite data type TEXT. SQLite does not have a data type LONGITUDE / LATITUDE. A list of all data types is available [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). In your case you could use REAL for floating point numbers or TEXT if you want to store the coordinates as strings (at the moment you are inserting strings, so I'll give example with it, but keep in mind that REAL is usually a better approach). Besides you only have 4 placeholders, but provide 6 parameters. Try something like this:

```
String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                            "%s TEXT" + " %s TEXT" + "%s TEXT)",
                            TaskContract.POI_NAMES, TaskContract.Columns.POI,
                            TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE, TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE);
```

This needs to be changed too:

```
sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TaskContract.POI_NAMES+TaskContract.LONGITUDES+TaskContract.LATITUDES);
```

When you drop a table, you need to specify only its name - in your case this is `TaskContract.POI_NAMES`. Adding the column names would just make the SQL code incorrect and your statement would be rejected (i.e. return an error). Make it like this:

```
sqlDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TaskContract.POI_NAMES);
```

A few issues here too:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.clear();
                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.POI,poi);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.POI_NAMES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);


                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE,longit);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.LONGITUDES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.LATITUDE,lat);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.LATITUDES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

When calling `insertWithOnConflict` you provide a table name and a collection of key-values which represent each of the columns. In short you need to call `insertWithOnConflict` once for each record you want to insert (not for each column in this record). Try this code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(TaskContract.Columns.POI,poi);
values.put(TaskContract.Columns.LONGITUDE,longit);
values.put(TaskContract.Columns.LATITUDE,lat);
db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.POI_NAMES,null,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

After these changes you could delete these fields - they won't be needed:

```
public static final String LONGITUDES = "longs";
public static final String LATITUDES = "lats";
```

Let me know if it works or you need some more assistance! :)